# Saving first and last frame of a video as an image on Android

Tags: android, video, frame

I want to save the first and last frame of a video as an images.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: try getFrameAtTime() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#getFrameAtTime(long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the [`MediaMetadataRetriever`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html) class.

More specifically its [`getFrameAtTime(long)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#getFrameAtTime%28long%29) method.

To get the time of the last frame use [`getDuration()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#getDuration%28%29), which will return the duration of the video.

*Note: This is available **from** API level 10!*

Comment: I have this problem: if I put retriever.getFrameAtTime(0) I get a frame from somewhere in my Video (not first frame). For retriever.getFrameAtTime(myVideoView.getDuration()) or retriever.getFrameAtTime(myVideoView.getCurrentPosition()) I have the same problem. What is the time from video for first and last frame :?

Comment: use `retriever.getFrameAtTime(0, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);` and the same thing for the last frame

Comment: @Gabrielle Video is stored as Intra and non Intra (Picture frames) This API will return the closest non- Intra frame.

Comment: is anyone else seeing a problem with getFrameAtTime where it only returns a bitmap of the first frame, no matter which time you pass in?

Comment: any solution to this yet? I see same frames appear for any time I pass in.

Comment: yes, even i am also getting same fist frame for all the time. Any solution ?

Comment: hey , i got it. just you have to set the video duration in microsecond as answered bellow by Nihad

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MediaMetadataRetriever` class.

And method `getFrameAtTime(timeUs)` method. timeUs is in microseconds.